# how to prevent p:messages from being updated when update global PrimeFaces growl

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using PF 5.3, with JSF 2.2

I have a global p:growl which will be updated in the backBean, the problem is that whenever I update the the global p:growl, other p:messages are updated as well with same data. I want a way to update only the global growl in the action method in the back bean, and other p:messages should not be updated.

xhtml:

```
<h:body>
    <p:growl id="growlGeneralMessages" showDetail="true" sticky="true" globalOnly="true" /> 
    <h:form id="register_new_student" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
       <p:messages autoUpdate="true" />
       <p:commandButton id="new_student_action" value="Add"  update="register_new_student_panel" validateClient="true" action="#{teacherPresentation.newStudentAction()}" />
   </h:form>
</h:body>
```

back bean:

```
public String newStudentAction() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Wrong username or password!", "");
    context.addMessage(null, message);
    context.getExternalContext().getFlash().setKeepMessages(true);

    return "teacher.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

I tried two things but they didn't work:

1- to remove the attribute autoUpdate from p:messages (fail)

2- to specify the client id in addMessage method

context.addMessage(null, message); --> context.addMessage("growlGeneralMessages", message); (that fail too)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have two options to control it

## Key option

Both, `p:growl` and `p:messages` has a `for` attribute which lets you bind that components to a key. You can control what messages do you want to show on every component, using that key as `clientId` parameter of `FacesContext.addMessage()`

This is what I mean:

```
<p:growl for="growlKey"/>
```

And in BackBean:

```
facesCtx.addMessage("grwolKey", facesMsg);
```

## Severity option

Again, both components has a `severity` parameter that lets you control what messages are shown in. For example you could use `info` for growl and `error` for messages, or whatever.

When creating a `FacesMessage` you cans specify severity using `FacesMessage.Severity`.

```
FacesMessage facesMsg = new FacesMessage(
   FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Your title", "Your Message")
```

Hope it helps!